# Suppress unknown or uninitialised column

Tags: r, warnings, lapply

I keep getting the following warning:

> "Warning messages:
> 1: Unknown or uninitialised column: `LinkStatus`.
> 2: Unknown or uninitialised column: `LinkStatus`. “

but the Column `LinkStatus` does not exist.

Below is my code for reading in multiple `.xlsx` files:

```
DR <- list.files(path = Delivery_Status_Rep,pattern = "*.xlsx",full.names = TRUE ) %>% 
  lapply(read_xlsx, skip = 10) %>% 
  bind_rows
```

I have checked the files and there is no such column. I have also run `names()` and it not showing. I have tried `dplyr::select(.data)` to try and just select the Columns that are there/I want but nothing works.

Is there a way to suppress a specific warning because as soon as I start working with the data I get warning after warning?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use `suppressWarnings`, but warnings are useful.  Try to check the result in the `list`  i..e `str(yourlistout)` i.e. before the `bind_rows` code is applied

Comment: thanks akrun, no sing of the extra column, I absolutely agree warning are very useful, but this is “false” do you know of a what to suppress just that one? If not an alternative way to read in xlsx files and skip the first 10 rows

Comment: there are multiple packages to read from excel.  You may try another package

Comment: try 'openxlsx', 'readxl' packages or if you can save data in `.csv' and try with fread from data.table (@akrun is co-author i think ;-) thank him for that wonderful package)

Comment: @anuanand i am not co-author - just a correction

Comment: Sorry but i read so much from your comments/answers on data.table when i was learning it that whenever i come across your name at SO, i link you with that only. (and am still not master at it as you are) Cheers! ( Not meaning to discredit anyone.)

Comment: Thanks will give some of the other packages a try, will feed back when I find some thing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi found a solution and thought it may be useful for others.
I have simply added as.data.table

```
DR <- list.files (path = Delivery_Status_Rep,    
                     pattern = "*.xlsx",
                     full.names = TRUE) %>% 
lapply(read_xlsx,skip = 10) %>%
 bind_rows   

DR<- as.data.table(DR)
```

Works a treat now